# Delete from multiple tables using order by and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete from two tables which have a relationship using ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT.

```
DELETE FROM my_rel_table AS t1
LEFT JOIN my_photo_table AS t2 ON t2.typeid = t1.typeid
WHERE t1.relid = 1 
AND t1.type = 1
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Obviously the above does not work since mysql does not accept the order by and limit using an inner join.

Table structure is as follows:

```
my_rel_table
id relid relno typeid type
int int int int tinyint

my_photo_table
typeid pos_x pos_y width height
int    int   int   int    int
```

Comment: what is sppr.ppr_id ?

Comment: In addition to the above, are you trying to delete from my_rel_table, my_photo_table or from both?

Comment: Hi sorry, edited the above, I want to delete from both tables actually. Order by and limit do not work when you have a left join. Is it possible in one query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing it using a JOIN against a subselect to get the highest id from the my_rel_table

```
DELETE my_rel_table, my_photo_table
FROM my_rel_table 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxId
    FROM my_rel_table 
    WHERE relid = 1 
    AND type = 1
) Sub1
ON my_rel_table.id = Sub1.MaxId
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_photo_table ON my_photo_table.typeid = my_rel_table.typeid
WHERE my_rel_table.relid = 1 
AND my_rel_table.type = 1
```

Not directly tested as I have no test data!

EDIT - Couple of attempts to do the top 5, but again not tested

```
DELETE my_rel_table, my_photo_table
FROM my_rel_table 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id
    FROM my_rel_table 
    WHERE relid = 1 
    AND type = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
) Sub1
ON my_rel_table.id = Sub1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_photo_table ON my_photo_table.typeid = my_rel_table.typeid
WHERE my_rel_table.relid = 1 
AND my_rel_table.type = 1
```

Or a different way.

```
DELETE my_rel_table, my_photo_table
FROM my_rel_table 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, @Counter:=@Counter+1 AS ItemCounter
    FROM my_rel_table 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0) Sub1
    WHERE relid = 1 
    AND type = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
) Sub1
ON my_rel_table.id = Sub1.id
AND Sub1.ItemCounter <= 5
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_photo_table ON my_photo_table.typeid = my_rel_table.typeid
WHERE my_rel_table.relid = 1 
AND my_rel_table.type = 1
```

Comment: worked perfectly mate! but.. what if I want to make the limit to say delete 5 rows of data? Can you please explain it to me so I could understand more how it works instead of I, just 'copying and pasting it'?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Deleting the top 5 from my_rel_table (and their matching rows from my_photo_table) is rather more complex. Probably needs to be done using user variables. I will try and knock something up.

Comment: yep, second one works perfectly. Didn't know it was this complex to just add ordering and limit with an inner join delete. Which query would be the fastest to execute? And Could you please explain the second query? Thanks!

Comment: The last one is using a subselect to return a list of the ids in order, with a sequence number added. The CROSS JOIN it uses is just to initialise the counter used for the sequence number. Then this counter is incremented for each row. In the INNER JOIN against that subselect it just checks that the sequence number is less than or equal to 5.

Comment: thank you very much for you help, now I understand why you went for such an approach