# Right syntax to use near ORDER BY when I try to delete some number of rows

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, sql-order-by, limit

When I try to delete some rows from tables (rows got from joined tables) (Ex : if I get 10 records, then need to delete first 2 records) using ORDER BY ASC and LIMIT = 2.

But getting error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY sales_flat_quote.entity_id ASC LIMIT 2' at line 9

Below is my code:

```
DELETE table1,table2,table3
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.entity_id=table2.quote_id
LEFT JOIN table3 on table1.entity_id=table3.quote_id
WHERE table1.entity_id <= 101
ORDER BY table1.entity_id ASC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Which tables you wanted to delete? All three tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

```
DELETE table1,table2,table3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT entity_id 
            FROM table1
            WHERE entity_id<= 101
            ORDER BY entity_id ASC
            LIMIT 2
           ) sub1
ON table1.entity_id=sub1.entity_id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.quote_id = table1.entity_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.entity_id = table3.quote_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a multi-table delete and the documentation [states the following](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

> *You cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a multiple-table DELETE.*

Some workarounds are eventually possible with nested selects. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344294/13601221) to a similar question.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The documentation states '`If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are deleted in the order that is specified. The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be deleted. These clauses apply to single-table deletes, but not multi-table deletes.`

Comment: @Philip Petrov  _Is there any way to delete only 2 records by joining the tables if not from LIMIT?_

Comment: @K4M Any solution for the above query?

Comment: I see that you already fount it - a nested select which orders and limits the rows which is joined towards the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If temp table is acceptable to you, you can try something like this. Not superb but straightforward solution.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempToBeDeleted (
     id_table1 INT NOT NULL
   , id_table2 INT NOT NULL 
   , id_table3 INT NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO (id_table1, id_table2, id_table3)
SELECT DISTINCT table1.primary_key, table2.primary_key, table3.primary_key
FROM 
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.entity_id = table2.quote_id
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.entity_id = table3.quote_id
WHERE table1.entity_id <= 101
ORDER BY table1.entity_id ASC LIMIT 2;

DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3
FROM
    TempToBeDeleted
    INNER JOIN table1 ON TempToBeDeleted.id_table1 = table1.primary_key
    INNER JOIN table2 ON TempToBeDeleted.id_table2 = table2.primary_key
    INNER JOIN table3 ON TempToBeDeleted.id_table3 = table3.primary_key
;

DROP TABLE TempToBeDeleted;
```